# Applying real time filters in iPhone app

Tags: ios, video, filter, imagefilter

Are there any open source libraries that can help me do the following to a photo & video sharing app for the iPhone:

• User has real-time filter over camera when taking images/video. User can swipe horizontally to change the filter over the camera
• User can hold down the image to compare before and after filter.
• User can select a number of different fonts to overlay the image (option 1)
• User can swipe vertically over image to adjust intensity of filter
• User can swipe vertically over video to adjust intensity of filter

Thanks much
- R

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **GPU** Image filter class and there is also category provided by apple of **UIImage** class.

Answer (score 0):

I have just open-sourced VideoShader, a real-time video processing technology. The sample app might be a good starting point.

https://github.com/snakajima/videoshader